# Match pattern within angled brackets, ignoring spaces, with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have a set of patterns in a file that are in angled brackets (`<` and `>`). Within a bash script, I'm trying to match patterns that do not contain spaces within angled brackets using `grep`. For example, if my file has:

```
<shouldmatchthis>
<should not match this>
```

I want to return `<shouldmatchthis>` and ignore `<should not match this>`. I can match all angled brackets with `grep '<.*>' myfile.txt`, but I'm not sure how to ignore the content with spaces.

I'm open to other shell tools other than grep, if there is one that is better suited for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then don't `grep` for spaces:

```
grep '<[^ ]*>' myfile.txt
```

The bracket expression `[^ ]*` matches any character (any amount, zero or more) except the space character.